# SQL 2 Rows into 1

Tags: sql, inner-join

Below is a SQL script to see how many customers purchased both products, as well as how many customers purchased either of the two products.

I would like to be able to return a result set with one column for the first product, one column for the second, one column for Count with Both, and one column for Count with Either.

**Instead** it returns a column for each of the counts and a single NULL column for the `ProductID`.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT b.CustomerID) AS "Count with Both",
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.CustomerID) AS "Count with Either",
    b.ProductID
FROM
    LocationCode z
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT ProductID, CustomerID
     FROM LocationCode a
     WHERE a.ProductID IN ('MP040') AND a.ProductID IN ('OG010')) b ON z.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT ProductID, CustomerID
     FROM LocationCode b
     WHERE b.ProductID IN ('MP040', 'OG010')) c ON z.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
GROUP BY 
    b.ProductID
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  `LocationCode` is an odd name for a table that has customer/product relationships.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use a self-join and aggregation.  The following does what you want for all pairs of products:

```
with cp as (
      select customerid, productid,
             count(*) over (partition by customerid) as num_customers
      from locationcode
      group by customerid, productid
     )
select cp1.productid, cp2.productid, cp1.cnt as cnt1, cp2.cnt as cnt2,
       count(*) as both
from cp cp1 join
     cp cp2
     on cp1.customerid = cp2.customerid and
        cp1.productid < cp2.productid
group by cp1.productid, cp2.productid, cp1.cnt, cp2.cnt ;
```

You can of course add `where` filters if you only want results for certain products.

Comment: This looks like it may be a good start. Follow up, where are you getting the cp1.cnt and cp2.cnt from?

Comment: @g_PD . . . Those are defined in the CTE `cp`.